# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError (Win 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am receiving the "Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError" error. To solve this I added the line `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin'` to my development.rb file. However I also encounter the "image has contents that are not what they are reported to be", which I previously solved with `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'`

The issue is that upon having both lines in my development.rb file, one line will over-write the other, such that if the line with `'/usr/local/bin'` is first, I will receive the "Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError" error and if the `'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` is first, I will receive the "image has contents that are not what they are reported to be" error.

In my user.rb I have the following:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :styles => {:small => "150x150>"}
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :avatar
```

If I do not include the styles, and I remove the `'/usr/local/bin'` line from my development.rb file, the uploading of images works fine.

I have attempted the following instructions on https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip to not need the `'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` line by editing the PATH variables but that did not work.

Comment: Have you got [`file.exe`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) on your system? I wrote that part in the Paperclip docs

Comment: @Richard Peck Yeah I downloaded it from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Comment: Let me write something for you

Comment: Using `usr/local/bin` is linux only btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**file.exe**

The problem seems to be that you don't have access to `file.exe`.

`file.exe` allows Paperclip / ImageMagick to identify the attachments you upload. It is important for the likes of validating against the file type (`validates_attachment :attachment, content_type ...`).

When you use Paperclip / Imagemagick, you therefore have to ensure you have `file` accessible to Ruby. I wrote the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file) in Paperclip for this as I had the same issue:

---

Since you have already installed [`file`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm), you need to make it accessible to Ruby. There are two ways to do this; add it to the `PATH` system var, **or** explicitly define in `devleopment.rb`:

**PATH**

> 1. Click "Start"
> 2. On "Computer", right-click and select "Properties"
> 3. In Properties, select "Advanced System Settings"
> 4. Click the "Environment Variables" button
> 5. Locate the "PATH" var - at the end, add the path to your newly installed `file.exe` (typically `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`)
> 6. Restart any CMD shells you have open & see if it works

Using the above will *not* require any definitions in `development.rb`.

--

**development.rb**

If you wanted to define the path explicitly (again, **only** if you don't use the "PATH" method), you can add the following to `development.rb`:

```
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'
```

`/usr/local/bin` is *only* for Linux; you only need to define the `command_path` once.

---

**Update**

The following got the system working:

1. We installed the [`rmagick`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick/versions/2.15.4) gem (`gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- '--with-opt-dir="..."'`)
2. We put all the PATH vars into the *system* `PATH` var (as opposed to the user-only var):

[image]
3. We tested `file` and `imagemagick` prior to testing with Rails
4. Once both were working, we tested with Rails & it worked

Comment: If you want to jump into chat, I'll help

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat due to not having the 20 reputation for it. How should I be connecting my command_path to ImageMagick?
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16' ?

Comment: Hmm okay; your `development.rb` should *only* have ` Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'` for Paperclip, nothing else (`usr/local/bin` etc)

Comment: With only ` Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'` I get the 
Avatar Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Comment: Do you have a github repo I could look at?

Comment: I continue to receive the Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError with only ` Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'`

Comment: Is that the path where you installed `file`?

Comment: Yeah, it is where I installed file. How should I be telling Paperclip where ImageMagick is?

Comment: ImageMagick should be in your `PATH` var, along with `file`. Do you want to hop onto Teamviewer? I'll get it working for you

Comment: How should I invite you?